# Splice Method issue

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am deleting an element from an array:

```
this.my_events.splice(this.current_event);
this.current_event=null;
this.old_event=null;
jQuery('#eventModal').modal('hide');
```

When I add three or more items in an array and then delete any one of them it deletes all the items and returns null without refreshing the page. I am using **Vue.js**.

If I then refresh the page, then the two elements are shown. What's this issue?

Comment: Without the full code, we can't help you.

Comment: "_If I then refresh the page ..._" Manipulating the DOM with JS doesn't save the changes to the server.

Comment: I am passing API with vue .js this is the Function with Splice method Vue Pop method is working fine but i dont want to use that because it makes the frontend harder to load

Answer (score 2):

Your are not specifying an index location to delete.

Try this:

```
 this.my_events.splice(index, 1); // the 1 represents how many items to delete
        this.current_event=null;
        this.old_event=null;
        jQuery('#eventModal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: may not solve all the OPs problems, but this is one of the problems

Comment: let me try frind

Comment: @Jake G now its not Deleting the item without refreshing the Page

Comment: @Asad can you please post more code then. If the deletion is working but not updating it, the problem most likely exists elsewhere.